# VB.net Place JSON from URL result in text box

Tags: json, vb.net, url, textbox

My JSON String

```
{

"name": "username",
"place": {
  "name": "placename",
}
```

My Code So Far

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://json-request.com/myjson"), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            textbox.text = ("placename")) 
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

How could i pull this from a URL and parse the placename in one textbox and the username in another textbox in VB.net please if it helps i am using Visual Studio 2013 And A Windows Form

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that `rawresp` contains json as posted in this question, following code snippet demonstrates one way to get "username" and "placename", then display them in two different `TextBox`s :

```
......
Dim jResults As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(rawresp)
usernameTextbox.text = jResults("name").ToString()
placenameTextbox.text = jResults("place")("name").ToString()
......
```

Comment: yeah, my bad, it was C# syntax.

Comment: no problem i posted underneath so you can see what my changes were

Answer (score 0):

thanks i had to change the [] to () and change it slightly to

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
usernameTextbox.text = jResults("name").ToString()
placenameTextbox.text = jResults("place")("name").ToString()
```

but it worked :D

but when the request is a 404 i get an exception thrown do you have any idea how i could handle the error or any other errors as im going to use a text box to make changes to the URL and display a message box?

Thanks Again

Comment: at which line the exception thrown, is it `JObject.Parse(rawresp)`? if that is the case you can check `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawresp)`

Comment: its at `response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)` line 17

Comment: one more thing, this isn't the way this site works. Next time, you should post new question for other problem, even if context is the same. We are building knowledge base here, so it is not only you get your problem solved, but also others having the same problem can solve it using given answers. Thanks

Comment: ah i see sorry about that :)

Comment: thanks i added another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948825/vb-net-json-from-url-to-textbox-how-can-i-handle-errors

Comment: nice, really appreciate that :)