# VB.Net JSON From URL To Textbox How Can I Handle Errors?

Tags: json, url, http-status-code-404

My JSON String Returned

```
{

"name": "username",
"place": {
  "name": "placename",
}
```

My Code At The Moment

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://my-json.com/json"), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
        usernameTextbox.text = jResults("name").ToString()
        placenameTextbox.text = jResults("place")("name").ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()

    End Try
```

But when i get an error like 404 i get an exception

```
system.net.webexception: The server returned an error (404) Not Found.
```

this happens at the line

```
response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

please could you advise me on how i can handle this error and output a message to a messagebox

Thanks

Comment: You are using `Try/Catch` block already, it should go to `catch` block and display the message box if exception occur inside `try` block. Isn't that the case?

Comment: there was something odd in the code i re-wrote it and it seemed fine after :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems i had to change

```
    Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
```

To

```
Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
```